# how to change the max size of media upload? video audio wp 4.9.6

Tags: uploads

I'm using wordpress 4.9.6, and the max file size upload is now 8Mb. I used to upload 50+Mb video and audio, but it has changed. how can I change that to 100Mb?

Comment: Has anything changed with your host? Are you 8MB away from your site's quota? Is a plugin setting an upload cap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is something you can increase in your php.ini settings with your host server admin. I've found this resource for you: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/